# how do I display an event a day before it happens?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I'm currently building a website for event schedules and such, so basically it displays all the upcoming events and the date of it, and what I want it to do is to sort of highlight the event a day before the actual event happens.

Comment: Please show how you are storing your events and if possible, how to replicate the situation.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the events??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/ Fix your tags.

Comment: Compare the date of the event with today's date. If it's one day less than today, add a highlight. There are plenty of date libraries you can use to do that. It's not clear where you're up to so far or where you're stuck. It would make sense to clarify the question. If you're looking to display events on a website you might also want to consider using a ready-made calendar UI, there are a few around such as https://fullcalendar.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let a = new Date(); // today date, will be updated everyday
let b = targetDate; // you need to set this to whichever date you want to check.

a.setDate(a.getDate()+1); // make current date increase by 1;

if(a == b){  // check if target date is equal to today's date + 1
  alert('Today is the day you were waiting for.'); // trigger required event here
}
```

You can check multiple dates here using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/).  It makes handling these types of problems much eaiser.

But to be more helpful, what you want to do is determine if the date you're comparing is greater than the beginning of tomorrow, and less than the end of tomrrow.  There's lots of ways to do this, but the most straight-forward way for a new dev would be something like this in "vanilla" JavaScript:

```
function isTomorrow(date) {
  var now = new Date();
  var tomorrow = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1));
  var startOfTomorrow = tomorrow.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  var endOfTomorrow = tomorrow.setUTCHours(23,59,59,999);
  return Number(date) > startOfTomorrow && Number(date) < endOfTomorrow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let date = new Date()
    
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)
    
    date;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 